# C Standard Library for Win32/Win64 other than MSCRT

Tags: c, windows

In unix/linux world, there are a couple of different C Standard Library implementations to choose from and link against, but although I spent some time searching for an alternative to Microsoft's C Runtime Library, I couldn't find anything.

I also took a look at MinGW and CLANG docs and saw that they both link against MSCRT under Windows.

My question is: Is there any alternative C Standard Library implementation to use under Win32/Win64?
If yes, I'd appreciate you mentioning whether static and/or dynamic linking is supported by that implementation.

Comment: There might be a few alternatives, but in the Linux world is in 99.99% of all cases just the GNU C library.

Comment: As for your question, *why* do you want to learn about possible alternatives? What problems do you have? Is it just curiosity? And lastly, if you read ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you will see that this question is off-topic here. If you have a problem other than plain looking for library alternatives, then please ask about *that* problem instead.

Comment: My most important point of concern is speed. I was looking to find a library that is faster.

Comment: Do you have some requirements for a certain performance? Then don't *start* by worrying about that requirement. Instead start by making a working, well-documented (and commented), readable and maintainable program. Then test a release build against your requirements. If it's "to slow" *then* you can start worry about performance. And do some measurements, benchmarking and profiling to find the hot-spots and bottlenecks, and improve those (and *only* those), leaving plenty of comments about what you do and why. Premature optimizations are usually bad.

Comment: If there is *no* specific performance-specific requirement, then "good enough" almost always *is* good enough.

Comment: If you have a single-threaded program, which is not sharing any data structures with any DLL, you should use the static single-threaded CRT for best performance.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, when not using Microsoft's MSVC compiler, there is only the MinGW standard library and it's successor MinGW-w64 (which supports both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit).

Both GCC and LLVM/CLang toolchains targetting MinGW-w64 exist (see https://winlibs.com/ and https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw).

These days there is also a choice between which Windows' underlying libraries to use: MSVCRT or UCRT. The former is the one used since the early days of win32, the latter is for more recent Windows versions (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/upgrade-your-code-to-the-universal-crt).